# Ruby on Rails: Is there a method to retrieve an array of data from the database without Rails needing to instantiate anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model that I'm trying to retrieve an array of data from, and I don't need the data to be instantiated into Ruby objects.  In fact, that just introduces an extra step into my code to step through the objects and generate a new array with just the data I need.

Example:

```
class Book
  #has attribute in database title
end
```

I would like to generate an array which contains all the titles of all the Books in the database.  What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ActiveRecord gives you a direct hook to the current environment database, allowing you execute SQL statements and returning the result in basic structures (arrays or hashes). See: http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html

For example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values("SELECT title FROM books")
```

Will return an array of book titles (strings).  This will not instantiate any ActiveRecord instances and will be more memory efficient for your application.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Now.. if you want to select multiple fields in the same query you need to write the table name again, like this:

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows("SELECT books.title, books.author FROM books")

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 3.x you could use `pluck` to return an Array of the desired attributes straight off of the DB without instantiating an object.

```
titles = Book.where(:foo => 'bar').pluck(:title)
#SELECT TITLE FROM BOOKS WHERE FOO = 'BAR'
```

Comment: This is now the best answer, I think.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how Rails works. You could write some middle-ware or something that circumvents the framework but it's probably not worth your time. Rails is all about (or at least, has a focus on) developer productivity. Just do it like this:

```
titles = Book.find( :all ).map( &:title )
```

As for performance concerns (assuming your site grows) you simply start caching this result.

Comment: You could even optimize this a little and select only the field you need:

`titles = Book.find( :all, :select => 'title' ).map( &:title )`

Comment: True, also your comment reminded me about an ActiveRecord plugin I came across once called slim-attributes (http://slim-attributes.rubyforge.org/) that does some stuff along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gem `pluck_to_hash` https://github.com/girishso/pluck_to_hash

It works similar to `pluck` but returns array of Hashes

```
Post.limit(2).pluck_to_hash(:id, :title)
#
# [{:id=>213, :title=>"foo"}, {:id=>214, :title=>"bar"}]
#
```