# Simplifying limit and order AR query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a simpler and shorter way to declare this in Rails?

```
Message.where(conditions).limit(10).order("created_at desc")
```

Comment: How "ActiveRecord, find a range of ids" is related to your question?

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018453/best-practices-for-getting-a-list-of-ids-from-an-activerecord-model is helpful.

Comment: That seems like a pretty simple and short way to specify that many things. You could alternatively define it as a scope so you could reference it with the scope name in your controller

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to make the code shorter, but you could add a scope if you want a better interface:

```
Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :my_scope, where(conditions).limit(10).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Then you would simply query using `Message.my_scope`